# Prevent device notification client side with React Native Firebase when a FCM notification arrives (based on user preferences)

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'd like to know if there any a way to prevent the device display a notification when a **FCM message with a notification** arrives, in case the user has decided to mute notifications and only have them arrive silently (making them act as data only messages, but being notification messages). I imagine like, in the handler/callback call a method to prevent the device notification and do extra processing afterwards.

I know I can use data only messages, but that approach would be harder since I must use multiple topics or token lists and somewhat more backend logic to achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the message contains a `notification` property, it is automatically handled by the OS when the app is not active. There is nothing you can do to prevent that.

As you said: if the message *only* contains a `data` property, it is always passed to your code for handling, and you can decide what to do with it. So that's the way to go if you want full client-side control over whether a notification is displayed for a message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Then I will use multiple topics to send or data only or notification+data messages according to user preference.

Comment: And then from there, you can still show a Local Notification, if and when you want...